# Failing to see how @synchronized works with asynchronous blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

Suppose I have a function like the following one, that is called 30 times per second (this code is a simplification of a more complex code created by Apple that I am trying to understand. The idea of Apple's original code is this: like I said `doSomethingWithImage` is called 30 per second. So, the whole method has 1/30 of a second to do everything but imagine that `doSomethingThatWillTakeTime` takes more than expected and `doSomethingWithImage` is called again, while `doSomethingThatWillTakeTime` is already being executed. If this is the case, the code has to drop that image and do nothing.

```
// code...
@synchronized (self);
  [self doSomethingWithImage:image];
}

// ...

// call under @synchronized( self )
- (void)doSomethingWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.myImage = image;

    [self executeBlockAsync:^{ 

        UIImage *myImage = nil;

        @synchronized( self ) 
        {
            myImage = self.myImage; 
            if (myImage) { 
                self.myImage = nil; // drop the image
            }
        }

        if ( myImage ) { 
            [self doSomethingThatWillTakeTime:myImage];  
        }
    }];
}


 (void)executeBlockAsync:(dispatch_block_t)block
{
    dispatch_async( _myQueue, ^{
            callbackBlock();
    } );
}
```

My problem is that looking at this code I cannot see how this is doing that. I do not have a mental image of what lines are being execute in which order for that to occur. Probably I do not understand the role of `@synchronized` in doing that, on what exactly is being locked or not.

Comment: You can check [the code here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Listings/Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110-Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m-DontLinkElementID_10). See the method `captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that `@synchronized` does is to ensure "thread safe", synchronized interaction with some objects or variables. Specifically, it ensures that you don't access these resources from one thread while they're possibly being mutated elsewhere by another thread. If one thread is inside the `@synchronized(self) {...}` block and another thread encounters its own `@synchronized(self) {...}` block, this latter code won't start running that until the other thread finishes its `@synchronized` block.

This is just one of the many synchronization techniques outlined in the [Threading Programming Guide: Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1). (Or you can also use dedicated GCD queues, either serial queues or concurrent queues that use the reader-writer pattern, to manage this synchronization as outlined in [Concurrency Programming Guide: Migrating Away from Threads: Eliminating Lock-based Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3). But that's a separate topic altogether.)

In the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` method that you  [shared with us](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Listings/Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110-Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m-DontLinkElementID_10), they're just using `@synchronized` to ensure that the `_recordingStatus` and the `_recorder` don't change in one thread while you're using them from another thread. They accomplish this by making sure that all interactions with these variables (whether reading in one thread or updating in another) happens within their own `@synchronized { ... }` blocks.

But note that `@synchronized` does not serve any functional purpose beyond that thread safe interaction. All of the logic regarding "should I add a frame or not" is dictated by the simple `if` statements in that code. The `@synchronized` directives have nothing to do with that. They're just there to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't that the code "drops the image and does nothing".  The use of the term "drop" is probably a bit misleading; what happens is that images that haven't yet been delivered to the delegate are overwritten if there is a new image.

What happens is something like this:

- Image 1 is stored in `self.myImage`
- An asynchronous task is enqueued on a serial dispatch queue to process Image 1.
- When this task executes it picks up the current `self.myImage` and then clears `self.myImage`
- If a non-nil image was picked up, it is passed to `doSomethingThatWillTakeTime`

Later,

- Image 2 is stored in `self.myImage`
- An asynchronous task is enqueued on a serial dispatch queue to process Image 2
- Since it is a serial dispatch queue, if the first task isn't done, this task will wait.

Now say,

- Image 3 is stored in `self.myImage` - note that this doesn't check to see if `self.myImage` is nil, it just overwrites it, so if Image 2 was never processed it has been "dropped"
- An asynchronous task is enqueued on a serial dispatch queue to process Image 3, but it also has to wait
- Now, when the first task finishes, the second will execute.  It will pick up the value from `self.myImage` which is now Image 3 and clear `self.myImage`
- Image 3 is passed to `doSomethingThatWillTakeTime`
- When the second task completes, the third task will start.
- It will get `nil` from `self.myImage` do nothing.

So you can see how Image 2 was dropped since it was stale; Image 3 had already arrived, so there was no point in processing Image 2.

Essentially, this code implements a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of size 1

Answer (score 0):

The crucial thing is `executeBlockAsync`, which in turn calls `dispatch_async`. So the real work is dispatched to a background queue, which is most likely configured to be working sequentially. `doSomethingWithImage` immediately returns and will never take 1/30s.

So the dispatching guarantees that image processing is done serially. This works as long as image processing doesn't take more than 1/30s on average. Single images can take longer. If it persists to take longer, the queue will fill up.

I don't understand what `@synchronized` does in this code. It only makes sense if there is more code (not shown here) that uses the same `@synchronized` block.

Comment: You can check [the code here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Listings/Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110-Classes_RosyWriterCapturePipeline_m-DontLinkElementID_10). See the method `captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`

Comment: Yes, the queue is configured to work serially. And yes, there are more `@synchronized( self )` blocks. I don't fully understand the code flow but it seems they aren't call from `doSomethingWithImage:` but from some other event.

Comment: `@synchronised` ensures that the access to `self.myImage`, setting or getting, only occurs on a single thread at a time.  If one thread already has the lock on `self` then the other thread will wait until the lock is available

Comment: @Paulw11 - ok, but what I don't understand is how another call to `doSomethingWithImage` will not execute and drop the image. In other words, I am failing to see how a second call to `doSomethingWithImage` can identify that there is another one still running.-

Comment: The image is NOT processed in the call to `doSomethingWithImage`. It just contains the code for it. However, the code block enclosed by `^{ ... }` is executed asynchronously in a background queue. And that queue is configured to work serially. So it is ensured that it wont' work on two images in parallel.